# meaning of も in 毎日捨てるのも、もったいない。

Tags: grammar, particles

The sentence is from the やさしい日本語 blog. The author is talking about 残り湯 and what to do with it.

最近は、毎日お風呂にお湯をためて入っています。そのお湯（残り湯）をどうするのか？**毎日捨てるのも、もったいない。** ですから、洗たくに使っています。

Could you explain the meaning/function of も in the sentence in bold? It doesn't seem to mean "also" or "even"....

Comment: You can see find more similar examples here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/55970?lq=1

Comment: @naruto got it, thank you.